# Найти всю строку regex

Tags: python, re

Не получается найти всю строку вот по такой конструкции

```
^[А-В]$

АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙК
```

Хотя если убрать символы начала и конца строки, то всё заработает, но будет искать по одному символу.
У меня получилось найти, если я в конце добавляю знак +, что означает "хотя бы один символ и максимально длинная последовательность", если я всё правильно понял.

```
 [А-В]+
```

Можно ли как-то найти всю строку с символами от А до В через ^ и $?

Comment: Что означает фраза «найти всю строку с символами от А до В»? Вы хотите найти строку, которая может содержать любые буквы, но при этом должна содержать в себе хотя бы одну букву А, Б или В? Или вы что-то другое хотите? Почему вам принципиально иметь ^ и $?

Comment: Регулярное выражение `^[А-В]$` означает, что строка должна состоять из строго одного символа А, Б или В. Регулярное выражение `[А-В]+` найдёт любые наборы идущих подряд символов А, Б или В

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо